# Parse ruby object in JavaScript (Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

in my view i have one object, and want to work with this onject from javascript
i try to

```
  var js_obj  = jQuery.parseJSON('<%=raw @rails_obj.to_json %>');
```

it works. but if i have "'" symbols, new string symbols, ,,, in this object all fails.

Have somebody know good approach to do it?

Comment: thx Falcon.........it helps me :). I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JSON is valid Javascript right out of the box, so why not just do:

```
var js_obj = <%= @rails_obj.to_json %>;
```

Comment: +1! My brain left me. I cannot believe that i did not see that.

Comment: JSON it isn't object - it just a text

Comment: @Falcon: JSON is valid JavaScript. It works like this. JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a subset of JavaScript's syntax. This is the correct answer. Forget mine.

Comment: I got some syntax errors and had to add `<%= @rails_obj.to_json.to_s.html_safe %>` in order for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

I find this to be the best way. Worked everytime

```
 <%= javascript_tag "var obj = #{@obj.to_json}" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape all single-quotes then. ActionView has a helper for escaping JavaScript: [`ActionView::Helpers::JavaScriptHelper#escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html)

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5.X

controller

```
def new
      @organization_json = Organization.first().to_json
end
```

view

```
<script>
    var organization_json = <%= @organization_json.html_safe %>;
<script>
```